# ESXi Subnet and NAT

Tags: vmware-esxi, nat

I have leased an ESXi server (no license) and am currently able to manage it with a public IP Address.

I created a Windows VM and set this up with an additional public IP.

I would I like to setup a Class C internal network with NAT to the internet, but don't know how to get this done. Is this possible and could someone give me guidance to help get me started?

Comment: You mean your ESX got a public IP ? please buy a switch and hook your ESX to your switch and let a router handle the public side. Your VM you just plug it to a vswitch, that would make the server be inside the same LAN as the ESX if you want to keep that simple

Comment: I am leasing the server through a managed server provider, a switch is not an option. It is just a playground for me, so I am less security conscious.

Comment: Out of the box ESXi only deals with IP for its management interface, if you want NAT or any other kind of IP routing/firewalling/whatever you're going to need to either configure Windows, in this instance, or some form of router VM (pfsense gets good reports for this) to do this for you. Also if you have anyone around you who knows a bit more why not get them involved.

Comment: yup, just loaded pfSense, seems to do the trick. Sadly I am on my own so have to figure these things out for myself.

Comment: For reference, I used this guide: https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/virtualization/virtualizing-pfsense-with-vmware-vsphere-esxi.html, Really simple and works perfectly